# ListView hides Spinner in a GridLayout

Tags: android

The Spinner View is hid after I insert a ListView item.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:columnCount="2"
    tools:context="aloncompany.salary.MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/month"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"/>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/months"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Why does it happen?

By the way, I'm using GridLayout in the first place because I want to have the TextView and Spinner in the same row, which I can't (?) do in using LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by giving a specific width to your list view as opposed to match parent? I suspect it is happening because your 0th column(listview and textview) takes up the whole layout and 1st column(spinner) gets hidden

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding `android:layout_columnSpan="2"` to ListView.